# Use plugins specified in profile.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen, incanter

I added some plugins to my profile.clj. When I start a new repl they are downloaded correctly to my `.m2/repository directory`, but I'm unable to `(use '...)` them, because this is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`. So how can I use these plugins in a default repl outside of a project?

- Win 7
- clojure 1.7
- leiningen 2.5.3
- jdk1.8.0_25

  `user=> (use 'hiccup.core)`

  `FileNotFoundException Could not locate hiccup/core...`

Same with fresh downloaded Incanter 1.9.0

I know that there're a couple of questions with this error, but all in the context of projects, not for a default repl. Or can I only use plugins in a project repl?

Thanks in advance!

Here my profiles.clj

```
{:user
    {
    :java-cmd "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_25\\bin\\java.exe"
    :plugins [
      [cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]
      [incanter "1.9.0"]
      [hiccup "1.0.5"]
    ]
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably add hiccup (and incanter) to :dependencies section

```
{:user
    {
    :java-cmd "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_25\\bin\\java.exe"
    :plugins [
      [cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]
    ]
    :dependencies [
      [incanter "1.9.0"]
      [hiccup "1.0.5"]
    ]
   }
 }
```

also, i guess you should better add specific libraries to project.clj for every project that requires them, rather than adding them to global deps.